# Is it possible to share a object between multiple processes in Java ？

Tags: java

I have a class MyClass with a open() and release() method.

process1 invoke the open(), and if process2 startup , the release() should be invoked in process1 firstly and then invoke the open()

PS: process1 and process2 are two different process.

How to do it ?

Comment: I had thought Java generally ran in a single process. Do you mean two different threads?

Comment: @Sherz No. I mean two different processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can export a remote object from a JVM and call its methods remotely from another JVM process or indeed another host. This is called Remote Method Invocation (RMI).